# Images not linking to reply

Tags: bug, comments, chat, images

I clicked on the "Link my next chat message as a reply to this" arrow after a comment (as shown here):

[image]

and when I did, I got this in my chat window:

[image]

so I then clicked on the upload button, selected a picture from my computer, and clicked on the upload button.

However, when my picture posted, it did not show as being linked to the original comment. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks Tim, I think that is exactly what I'm experiencing, but after looking through the ReadMe for SEChatModifications, I didn't see any explicit listing for uploading an image in a reply. What would be the exact key combinations?

Comment: Urgh, yeah, I should update that...If I recall correctly it only supports you clicking the reply arrow as you were doing and then pressing the upload button, the difference being that it preserves the reply ID so that the image will be linked. Scripts aside, you can edit the existing message to link to the message you were replying to, it's just kind of inconvenient.

Comment: Thanks Tim! Unfortunately, I don't understand what "you can edit the existing message to link to the message you were replying to, it's just kind of inconvenient" means...how would I edit the message, because once you click on the first upload button, it takes you to the select image dialog box and from there, the only option is to click on the second upload button, but from there, there is no option to edit the message, only upload or cancel.

Comment: Ah, sorry for the confusion. After you've already uploaded the image and the message has been posted, you can edit the message (using the up arrow key, or the action menu via the arrow on the left) and then click the reply arrow of the message you had intended to link it to, and then submit that as an edit.

Comment: Thanks Tim! That works!